# Postback problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

When I postback on my "Review" page I check the modelstate and based on the results either redisplay the page or continue.  I have two issues.

When it fails validation it hangs up on partial views on that it loaded fine on the original get for the page.

**edit: This was caused by the [HttpGet]attribute being applied to methods for the partials views.  I removed the attribute and the partials renedered.**

If I comment out the partials then  the  the whole page diplays without any CSS styles..it's all text black and white.   **Edit: I'm still having the problem with the styles missing from the page**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Review()
    {
        var agmtsService = new AgreementsService();
        bool? scoreRelease = agmtsService.GetReleaseScoreIndicator();

        var vm = new ReviewModel {ReleaseScoreIndicator = scoreRelease};

        return View(vm);
    }




    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Review(ReviewModel model)
    {

        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);`**This is displaying the view w/o head section and no css**`
        }

        return RedirectToAction("CheckOut", "Financial");
    }
```

edit:

**View Model**

public class ReviewModel
{

```
    public bool? ReleaseScoreIndicator { get; set; }


    // Terms & Conditions
    [RequiredToBeTrue(ErrorMessage = "Eligibility Checkbox must be checked.")]
    public bool TermsEligibility { get; set; }

    [RequiredToBeTrue(ErrorMessage = "True and Accurate Checkbox must be checked.")]
    public bool TermsAccurate { get; set; }

    [RequiredToBeTrue(ErrorMessage = "Identity Release Checkbox must be checked.")]
    public bool TermsIdentityRelease { get; set; }

    [RequiredToBeTrue(ErrorMessage = "Score Release Checkbox must be checked.")]
    public bool TermsScoreRelease { get; set; }
```

}

public class RequiredToBeTrueAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return value != null && (bool)value;
    }
}

View

```
@model Registration.Web.Models.ReviewModel

@{
    ViewBag.DisableNavigation = true;
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.open_review').toggle(function() {
            $(this).text('Done').parents('.review_section').addClass('open_for_review').find('.review_content').slideDown('fast');
            return false;
        }, function() {
            $(this).text('Review').parents('.review_section').removeClass('open_for_review').find('.review_content').slideUp('fast');
            return false;
        });


    });



</script>

<div class='section module'>
          <h2>
            Please Review Your Application
          </h2>
          <p>
            Remember that your application fee is
            <strong>
              not refundable.
            </strong>
            Review your information below and make corrections before submitting.
          </p>
          <div class='review_section'>
            <a class="button open_review" href="#">Review</a>
            <h4>
              Identification
            </h4>
            @{Html.RenderAction("Review", "PersonalInformation");}
          </div>
          <div class='review_section'>
            <a class="button open_review" href="#">Review</a>
            <h4>
              Education
            </h4>
            @{Html.RenderAction("Review", "MedicalEducation");}   /////hangs here         
          </div>
          <div class='review_section'>
            <a class="button open_review" href="#">Review</a>                              
                 @{Html.RenderAction("Review", "PostGraduate");}////then hangs here
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='actions' id='terms_and_conditions'>






@using (Html.BeginForm("Review", "Agreements", FormMethod.Post))
{

    //"reviewForm","Agreements", FormMethod.Post

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


    <div class='group' id='data_release'>
        <h4>
            Data Release
        </h4>

        <p>
            Do you wish to release your scores?
        </p>
        <ul class='input_group'>
            <li>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ReleaseScoreIndicator, true)
                <label>
                    Yes
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ReleaseScoreIndicator, false)
                <label>
                    No
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>



    </div>











              <div class='group' id='terms'>
                  <h4>
                      Terms &amp; Conditions

                  </h4>
                  @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <th>
                          @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.TermsEligibility)  
                         @* @Html.CheckBox("terms_eligibility")*@

                      </th>
                    <td>
                      <label for='terms_eligibility'>
                        I currently meet all of the
                        <a href="" target="_blank"> requirements</a>
                        and have read the
                        <a href="" target="_blank">Information</a>
                      </label>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <th>
                          @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.TermsAccurate) 
                        @*  @Html.CheckBox("terms_accurate")*@

                      </th>
                    <td>
                      <label for='terms_accurate'>
                        The information I've provided is true and accurate
                      </label>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <th>
                           @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.TermsIdentityRelease)  
                         @* @Html.CheckBox("terms_identity_release")*@

                      </th>
                    <td>
                      <label for='terms_identity_release'>
                        I authorize the release
                      </label>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <th>
                          @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.TermsScoreRelease) 
                          @*@Html.CheckBox("terms_score_release")*@

                      </th>
                    <td>
                      <label for='terms_score_release'>
                        I agree 
                      </label>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
              <div class='actions'>


                            <input type="submit" value="Go To Checkout" class="button" />




                  <a class="button" onclick="getForMasterPage('@Url.Action("CheckOut", "Financial")', null);">BYPASS</a>
              </div>

} </div>
```

Comment: Can we see your view and viewmodel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to set the ReleaseScoreIndicator on the return from being posted?  It looks like it gets set for the initial GET, but the subsequent one, it doesn't get set.  Does the view use that property?

Comment: yes, I accidentally erased that code.  I'll add it back in and see what happens

Comment: I added the code back for the release and it didn't make any difference. I still get the same results....it hangs on the MedEd partial.

Comment: What line in the Med partial does it hang on?  What does that view look like?

Comment: I figured out why it was hanging on two of the partials, in the controller for those partials there was a HttpGet attribute on the method(the partials are not updatable) so I removed the get and they worked.   Getting closer...still displays with no Styles...

Comment: I figured out what happened to the styles....all of the pages are being call by links that call javascript that associates a master page......